# Which of the following two inequalities related to kinematics is wrong with reason?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, calculus

Problem was this: For a particle moving in space with velocity $\vec{V}$, which of the following is incorrect?

- (A) $\left|\frac{\mathrm{d} \overrightarrow{\mathrm{v}}}{\mathrm{dt}}\right| \geqslant \frac{\mathrm{d}|\overrightarrow{\mathrm{v}}|}{\mathrm{dt}}$
- (B) $\int_{0}^{t}|\vec{V}| d t \geqslant\left|\int_{0}^{t} \vec{V} d t\right|$
- (C) $|\Delta \vec{v}| \leqslant \int_{t_{1}}^{t_{2}}|\vec{a}| d t$
- (D)$\frac{\mathrm{d}|\overrightarrow{\mathrm{v}}|}{\mathrm{dt}}=\frac{\mathrm{d} \overrightarrow{\mathrm{v}}}{\mathrm{dt}} \cdot\left(\frac{\overrightarrow{\mathrm{v}}}{\mathrm{v}}\right)$

My thought: A tells magnitude of atotal >= atangential which is true because atotal is √(acet^2 + atan^2) D tells a tan is atotal component in v direction which is true , now my query is related to B and C option is there a general way to show it true or false without going with examples?

Comment: uhm... it's late at night so I could be wrong but... they all seem right to me

Comment: Sir it might be possible as there was one option of none of these too .

Answer (score 0):

For B: use the fact that $|d\vec  r |=|\vec V| dt$ to transform the LHS into $\displaystyle \int_0^t |d\vec r|$, namely the path length.  The RHS represents the displacement magnitude.

Use the same logic for C -- transform both sides into an integral and then compare.